# Let the tasks race

Tags: c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

Suppose I have a BlockingCollection `OutputQueue`, which has many items. Current my code is:

```
    public void Consumer()
    {
        foreach (var workItem in OutputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            PlayMessage(workItem);
            Console.WriteLine("Works on {0}", workItem.TaskID);
            OutLog.Write("Works on {0}", workItem.TaskID);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
```

Now I want `PlayMessage(workItem)` running in the multiple tasks way because some workItem need more time, the others need less time. There are huge difference.

As for the method  `PlayMessage(workItem)`, it has a few service calls, play text to speech and some logging.

```
 bool successRouting = serviceCollection.SvcCall_GetRoutingData(string[] params, out ex);
 bool successDialingService = serviceCollection.SvcCall_GetDialingServiceData(string[] params, out excep);
 PlayTTS(workItem.TaskType); //  playing text to speech
```

So how to change my code?

What I thought was:

```
public async Task Consumer()
{
    foreach (var workItem in OutputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        await PlayMessage(workItem);
        Console.WriteLine("Works on {0}", workItem.TaskID);
        OutLog.Write("Works on {0}", workItem.TaskID);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you want multiple TTS operations going at the same time? So different threads will be saying different things at the same times?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It is a telephony application. Our clients are in the different location in US. As long as we have enough ports, play TTS at the same time is OK. Let's say AT&T, customers can use the service at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want parallelism with your PlayMessage, i would suggest looking into [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as it combines both parallel work with async, so you could await your work properly.

TPL Dataflow is constructed of Blocks, and each block has its own characteristics.
Some popular ones are:

```
ActionBlock<TInput>
TransformBlock<T, TResult>
```

I would construct something like the following:

```
var workItemBlock = new ActionBlock<WorkItem>(
    workItem =>
    {
        PlayMessage(workItem);
        Console.WriteLine("Works on {0}", workItem.TaskID);
        OutLog.Write("Works on {0}", workItem.TaskID);
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = // Set max parallelism as you wish..
    });

foreach (var workItem in OutputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    workItemBlock.Post(workItem);
}

workItemBlock.Complete();
```

Comment: If I don't want parallel,I just need async. How is the code? I am not sure can we apply async inside PlayMessage because it has services call serviceCollection.SvcCall_GetRoutingData etc?

Comment: In order to call an async method, it has to be async :). Im not sure i understand what you need then. This code sample will load your work in parallel, without using async.

Comment: According to your question, you said you wanted to use "multiple tasks" to call PlayMessage in parallel. This is what the code does.

Comment: I meant if MaxDegreeOfParallelism=1 and can we also await serviceCollection.SvcCall_GetRoutingData inside PlayMessage? Maybe my statement is not clear, sorry about it.

Comment: If you set MaxDegreeOfParllelism to 1, just run your code like you already do in a normal foreach loop, that isn't parallel. You can await PlayMessage only if your API exposes an async endpoint, which in this case i think it dosen't have, so i am guessing you wont be able to await your service call.

Comment: What is "getCustomerBlock" in your code? I think that it is "workItemBlock", typo?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution, not based on TPL Dataflow. It uses uses `SemaphoreSlim` to throttle the number of parallel playbacks (warning, untested):

```
public async Task Consumer()
{
    var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(NUMBER_OF_PORTS);
    var pendingTasks = new HashSet<Task>();
    var syncLock = new Object();

    Action<Task> queueTaskAsync = async(task) =>
    {
        // be careful with exceptions inside "async void" methods

        // keep failed/cancelled tasks in the list
        // they will be observed outside
        lock (syncLock)
            pendingTasks.Add(task);

        await semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (!task.IsCancelled && !task.IsFaulted)
                throw;
            // the error will be observed later, 
            // keep the task in the list
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }

        // remove successfully completed task from the list
        lock (syncLock)
            pendingTasks.Remove(task);
    };

    foreach (var workItem in OutputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        var item = workItem;
        Func<Task> workAsync = async () =>
        {
            await PlayMessage(item);
            Console.WriteLine("Works on {0}", item.TaskID);
            OutLog.Write("Works on {0}", item.TaskID);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        });

        var task = workAsync();
        queueTaskAsync(task);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(pendingTasks.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Also `Cannot convert lambda expression to type "System.Threading.Tasks.Task"`, which is in `queueTaskAsync(async()=>`